# How should I remove the resin from the resin tank?

Tags: resin, maintenance, cleaning, formlabs

We need to move our Formlabs Form 3 printer to a new room, and I would like to remove the resin from the resin tank. Is there a standard way to do this, and can I reuse the resin once I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

when moving the printer to a new room I would just remove the tank and then carefully move the tank to the new room after you moved the printer.

If you really need to empty the tank: The tank usually has a small indent in one of the corners. Just dump the contents of the tank through a resin strainer (a paper coffee-filter-like cone) back into the container it came in. Do this in a well ventilated area with no direct sunlight entering the room and don't let it spill on your skin. (no big deal if you touch it, just don't let it happen too often)

Don't forget to clean the tank thoroughly with paper rags and alcohol afterwards. Everything that stays will be stuck after some time

Comment: Please wear gloves

Comment: When there is a slight chance of me touching the resin, I do wear gloves. When just dumping the contents of a vat into another vat, I ususally don't. I trust my digits near a soldering iron, circular saw, kitchen oven, as well as some resin.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the resin. In some resins like ESD components can sediment down to the floor of the VAT. In that case the best option is really to empty
the tank and shake the bottle / container. Its one of the benefits of the [Solidator 3D-Printer](https://www.solidator.com) that the Solidator Resins do not sediment and you can keep the material in the tank for several keeps without issues.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the website that you linked to?